# Best/cleanest way to grab all the keys that end in url in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash that looks like this:

```
{
                         "id" => 108,
                   "position" => 0,
    "attachment_content_type" => "image/jpeg",
      "attachment_updated_at" => "2014-11-14T21:50:46.395Z",
           "attachment_width" => 1140,
          "attachment_height" => 1140,
                        "alt" => "",
              "viewable_type" => "Spree::Variant",
                "viewable_id" => 43,
                   "mini_url" => "xyz,
                  "small_url" => "http:blahblahblah",
                "product_url" => "http:blahblahblah",
                  "large_url" => "http:blahblahblah",
                 "xlarge_url" => "http:blahblahblah"
}
```

How can I use the splat * to grab all the keys that end in url? Is there a way to do that?

This Hash is in a serializer in Rails and I'm trying to nest the urls in a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{
   urls: { 
         mini_url: "blaaaah",
         (etc.)
         }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, are you trying to explicitly use a glob style syntax to filter the Hash keys instead of using `end_with?`? If so, you could try using a regex matcher: `key =~ /^.*_url$/`

Comment: Ah that works! So that's a glob and not a splat right?

Comment: No, that's a regular expression.

Comment: If your actual question is given in the title (to return an array of certain keys), you should not state the question in terms of any particular approach (using the splat operator). When you give an example, please make it as small as possible so that it still makes the point (here five keys would be plenty) and assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `h = { id=>...}`) so readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments, without having to define it. (See, for example, how Maurício's answer could be simplified.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by using the splat operator here but you can easily pull them with code like:

```
input = {
                         "id" => 108,
                   "position" => 0,
    "attachment_content_type" => "image/jpeg",
       "attachment_file_name" => "Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg",
                       "type" => "Spree::Image",
      "attachment_updated_at" => "2014-11-14T21:50:46.395Z",
           "attachment_width" => 1140,
          "attachment_height" => 1140,
                        "alt" => "",
              "viewable_type" => "Spree::Variant",
                "viewable_id" => 43,
                   "mini_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/mini/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
                  "small_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/small/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
                "product_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/product/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
                  "large_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/large/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
                 "xlarge_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/xlarge/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846"
}

urls = input.each_with_object({}) do |(key,value),acc|
  if key.end_with?("_url")
    acc[key] = value
  end
end

puts urls.inspect
```

Comment: aaah +1 for `end_with?`

Comment: My first reaction was that `input.keys.select...` would be more direct, but that creates an unneeded temporary array (`input.keys`). So, good on you. My only suggestion is a stylistic one: `acc[key] = value if key.end_with?("_url")`. You could also have said, "If `input` is your hash,...", rather than repeating the hash in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I use the splat * to grab all the keys that end in url? Is there a way to do that?

Splats cannot do that.

You can use `Hash#select`:

```
input = {
    "id" => 108,
    "position" => 0,
    "attachment_content_type" => "image/jpeg",
    "attachment_file_name" => "Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg",
    "type" => "Spree::Image",
    "attachment_updated_at" => "2014-11-14T21:50:46.395Z",
    "attachment_width" => 1140,
    "attachment_height" => 1140,
    "alt" => "",
    "viewable_type" => "Spree::Variant",
    "viewable_id" => 43,
    "mini_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/mini/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
    "small_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/small/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
    "product_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/product/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
    "large_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/large/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
    "xlarge_url" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/xlarge/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846"
}

require "pp"
pp input.select { |key, value| key.end_with?("_url") }
```

Output:

```
{"mini_url"=>
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/mini/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
 "small_url"=>
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/small/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
 "product_url"=>
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/product/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
 "large_url"=>
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/large/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846",
 "xlarge_url"=>
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/marketplace-staging.blueapron.com/app/public/spree/products/108/xlarge/Strainer_-_Blue_Apron_Marketplace_213.jpg?1416001846"}
```

Comment: `*` _is_ splat, but I don't see how that can be used to filter entries from a Hash.

Comment: The OP only wants the keys. Note you are using [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), so `.to_h` is redundant.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the `.to_h` tip. Fixed. Where does OP say that they want only keys? From the expected output? It seems OP does want a Hash with the keys ending with `_url`.

Comment: I thought both the title and the line you included in your answer indicated that only the keys were wanted, but that's unimportant since you could always tack on `.keys`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the hash, or do you want the values. If I only wanted the values I'd start by taking advantage of `keys` and `select`:

```
hash = {
  "id" => 108,
  "viewable_id" => 43,
  "mini_url" => "mini_url_value",
  "small_url" => "small_url_value",
}

hash.keys.select{ |k| k[/.*_url$/] } # => ["mini_url", "small_url"]
```

That uses `*`, but there's no reason to use it. From experience and testing I know it'd slow the check and waste CPU. Simplifying the pattern would be faster:

```
hash.keys.select{ |k| k[/_url$/] } # => ["mini_url", "small_url"]
```

Even faster is:

```
hash.keys.select{ |k| k.end_with?('_url') } # => ["mini_url", "small_url"]
```

From there I'd use `values_at` to get the associated values:

```
url_keys = hash.keys.select{ |k| k.end_with?('_url') } # => ["mini_url", "small_url"]
hash.values_at(*url_keys) # => ["mini_url_value", "small_url_value"]
```

It'd be easy to build a new hash:

```
url_keys = hash.keys.select{ |k| k.end_with?('_url') } # => ["mini_url", "small_url"]
url_keys.zip(hash.values_at(*url_keys)).to_h  # => {"mini_url"=>"mini_url_value", "small_url"=>"small_url_value"}
```

It's also possible to use `select` with the hash and convert the resulting array-of-arrays back to a new hash:

```
hash.select{ |k| k.end_with?('_url') } # => {"mini_url"=>"mini_url_value", "small_url"=>"small_url_value"}
```

I use the first way out of habit; It was the Perl-ish way and I wrote a lot of Perl, and it's compatible with old Rubies. `Hash.select` didn't return hashes for a long time and `to_h` wasn't available as part of Array for even longer.